# C# Custom Convert Method

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio

I have a question.
Firstly, I did a lot of research on this topic but I could not get any information about that I want to do.

Few days ago, I saw a custom method on my friend's IDE. He has a method and he can convert to anything (if can convert returns 1, if not returns 0) on anywhere. For example:

```
int a;
a.To<String>;
a.To<Bool>;
```

In that case, I think he defined something for to do that. When he started typing and using the method To<....> Visual Studio shows "String, bool, integer" etc.

As to my question, how can I do this? What is of this logic?

Thank you, regards.

Comment: Did you ask your friend how he did it?

Comment: It is a generic method - research [generics on MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/512aeb7t.aspx)

Comment: Hello, of course I did. But he did not tell me. If he did, I wouldnt ask here.